# INSERT INTO SET syntax in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I come from mySQL to SQL Server. Doesn't the following syntax work in SQL Server?

```
 INSERT INTO table SET fil1="234", fil2="324"
```

Is there an comparable statement in SQL Server?

Comment: What a confusing syntax! If I didn't know how to use web search to lookup the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), I'd have thought someone mixed up UPDATE and INSERT!

Comment: Both ansvers are useful thanks!

Comment: I actually detest the current SQL syntax. It seems fine working with small tables, but when a table starts to have a lot of columns, it is so much nicer to use the Col=value syntax.

Comment: Ya, we humans sometimes need to read insert statements too, MySQL's `field = value` syntax is far easier to ingest/comprehend.  Bummer this isn't supported with SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `SET` way to insert records is not [standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973846/insert-into-set-syntax-in-sql-server/6973868#6973868). If you need it to use similar sql's for updates and inserts, you should use Stored-Procedures in MS SQL-Server instead, for example:

```
CREATE Procedure tableInsertUpdate
(
     @ID int,
     @fil1 int,
     @fil2 int,
     @IDOut int OUTPUT
)
AS
     IF EXISTS(SELECT ID from table WHERE ID=@ID)
     BEGIN
        UPDATE table SET
            fil1 = @fil1 
            fil2 = @fil2 
        WHERE ID=@ID
        SET @IDOut=null
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO table 
         (fil1, fil2)
         VALUES
         (@fil1, @fil2 )
         SET @IDOut=scope_identity()
      END
```

Comment: This is not thread safe. You can fix it by making the exists check serializable, or by retrying on a duplicate key error. The last option is preferred, because making it serializable will generate deadlocks sooner or later.

Comment: You might also want to look at the MERGE statment in Books Online.

Answer (score 16):

```
INSERT INTO table (fil1, fil2) VALUES ('234', '324');
```

Comment: Insert have only this syntax? (so poor)

Comment: Not necessarily a bad thing. Since it's not SQL standard.

Comment: @KakYlia, it's 6 to one, half a dozen to the other.  They both require you to explicitly state your fields if you aren't INSERTing data for all fields.

Comment: @Kak: true, that's an attractive feature of MySql, other rdbms don't have it. MySql alternative insert syntax looks like property initializer, fields and values are next to each other. Easier to read

Comment: I hope they add this syntax to Sql Server, so it would look more C#-like. **INSERT Employee(fil1: '234', fil2: '234')** :-)