# How can i get the @@IDENTITY returned from a INSERT from MySQL (2008) using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, identity, sqlconnection, datareader

I Have this code to **INSERT** a value in the Arquivo table in C# :

```
  public int **_Salvar**(Arquivo arquivo)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string procedure = "STP_Arquivo_INSERT";
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection);
            comand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sistema_id", arquivo._Sistema_id);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arquivo_nome", arquivo._arquivo_nome);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arquivo_formato",                  
                                                          arquivo._Arquivo_formato);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arquivo_caminho", 
                                                          arquivo._Arquivo_caminho);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arquivo_tamanho", 
                                                          arquivo._Arquivo_tamanho);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arqiuvo_criacao", 
                                                          arquivo._Arqiuvo_criacao);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arquivo_pasta", arquivo._Arquivo_pasta);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = comand.ExecuteReader();
           // IDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();

           // return (int)dataReader.Read;

            int arq = -1;
            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
            //    arquivo._Sistema_id = (int)dataReader["sistema_id"];
            //    arquivo._arquivo_nome = dataReader["arquivo_nome"].ToString();
            //    arquivo._Arquivo_formato = dataReader["arquivo_formato"].ToString();
            //    arquivo._Arquivo_caminho = dataReader["arquivo_caminho"].ToString();
            //    arquivo._Arquivo_tamanho = dataReader["arquivo_tamanho"].ToString();
            //    arquivo._Arqiuvo_criacao = (DateTime)dataReader["arqiuvo_criacao"];
            //    arquivo._Arquivo_pasta = dataReader["arquivo_pasta"].ToString();
                arq = (int)dataReader["arquivo_id"];

            }
            return arq;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw (err);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

And I have this StoredProcedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STP_Arquivo_INSERT]
@sistema_id Int
, @arquivo_nome varchar(510)
, @arquivo_formato varchar (100)
, @arquivo_caminho varchar (510)
, @arquivo_tamanho varchar (20)
, @arqiuvo_criacao DateTime
, @arquivo_pasta VarChar (255)



AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
    Arquivo
    ( 
        sistema_id 
        , arquivo_nome 
        , arquivo_formato 
        , arquivo_caminho 
        , arquivo_tamanho 
        , arqiuvo_criacao 
        , arquivo_pasta 

    )
VALUES
    ( 
        @sistema_id 
        , @arquivo_nome 
        , @arquivo_formato 
        , @arquivo_caminho 
        , @arquivo_tamanho 
        , @arqiuvo_criacao 
        , @arquivo_pasta 

    )

DECLARE @ret INT
    SELECT @ret =  ISNULL(@@IDENTITY, -1)
    RETURN @ret

END
```

I want to be able to get  this @@IDENTITY that returns in SQl. but I can't do that with this INSERT(_Salvar). The DataReader has no return value...

:'(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9319609/284240 Note that you also need to make it an output paramater([`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx))

Comment: @Gabriel: You've tagged MySql but i assume it's MS-SQL-Server, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hm yes sorry, i'm noobie at programming stuffs, Thnx . Lloyd thx.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the sugestion didn't work as well for me...   the question I've post I guess, have some diferences that can't work as the sugestion

Comment: You have to declare it as output-parameter and set it at the end of your SP. Assuming your primary-key is `sistema_i`, at the beginning of the procedure: `@sistema_id Int OUTPUT` and at the end: `SET @sistema_id=scope_identity()` like in [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6973928/284240). The rest as in my other answer linked above.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hm now, it's clear to me! Thank Man it really works !