# Error ODBC MS SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, odbc

I am getting this error

`Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ''., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in D:\wamp\www\STAPP\sys_admin\1.php on line 23`

`Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ''., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in D:\wamp\www\STAPP\sys_admin\1.php on line 23`

---

```
<?php

require_once("../includes/database_connection.php");
$conn=odbc_connect('stapp','','');

if ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) )
{
$csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
exit('File not found.');

$sql = '';

if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {


$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` SET `column0` = '$data[0]',

`column1`=            '$data[1]', `column2` = '$data[2]';";

   $rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

  }
  fclose($handle);
}

// Insert into database

//exit( $sql );
exit( "Complete!" );
}
?>
```

---

Line number 23 is $rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

Can any please help me in the sql statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SET way to insert records is not standard [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973846/insert-into-set-syntax-in-sql-server/6973868#6973868). Better go for the standard way

```
INSERT into table (column0, column1, column2) values 
('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]');
```

Comment: Ohh I forgot `SET` is used in `mysql` not in `mssql`. :)